# Disabled/ Blocked users in AD are being displayed in SharePoint Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, people-search

It appears in our directory that disabled / blocked users in Office365 still show in the search.  When you search for such accounts and click on their picture and it opens Delve it actually says the information is not available.  So how we can ensure disabled / blocked users are filter out of our Search.  Can these accounts be removed from the SharePoint Search completely? If so, can anyone share me the steps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search queries the data from the User Profile Service. Deleting the User Profiles from the SharePoint Admin Center will (eventually after a crawl) remove the users from People Search results.

Comment: Wouldn't the user profiles will be back again in SP User Profiles after the sync?

Comment: Users who are disabled will not sync.